# Unable to connect erlang-application to cassandra using erlcassa

Tags: cassandra, erlang

I am unable to connect my Erlang application to Cassandra with ErlCassa.  I am getting the following error message:

```
11> {ok, Cl} = erlcassa_client:connect("0.0.0.0", 9160).   
** exception error: no case clause matching {'EXIT',{undef,[{thrift_client_util,new,
                                                                                ["0.0.0.0",9160,cassandra_thrift,[{framed,true}]],
                                                                                []},
                                                            {erlcassa_client,connect,2,
                                                                             [{file,"src/erlcassa_client.erl"},{line,41}]},
                                                            {erl_eval,do_apply,6,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,573}]},
                                                            {erl_eval,expr,5,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,364}]},
                                                            {shell,exprs,7,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,674}]},
                                                            {shell,eval_exprs,7,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,629}]},
                                                            {shell,eval_loop,3,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,614}]}]}}
     in function  erlcassa_client:connect/2 (src/erlcassa_client.erl, line 41)


10> {ok, Cl} = erlcassa_client:connect("localhost", 9160).
** exception error: no case clause matching {'EXIT',{undef,[{thrift_client_util,new,
                                                                                ["localhost",9160,cassandra_thrift,[{framed,true}]],
                                                                                []},
                                                            {erlcassa_client,connect,2,
                                                                             [{file,"src/erlcassa_client.erl"},{line,41}]},
                                                            {erl_eval,do_apply,6,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,573}]},
                                                            {erl_eval,expr,5,[{file,"erl_eval.erl"},{line,364}]},
                                                            {shell,exprs,7,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,674}]},
                                                            {shell,eval_exprs,7,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,629}]},
                                                            {shell,eval_loop,3,[{file,"shell.erl"},{line,614}]}]}}
     in function  erlcassa_client:connect/2 (src/erlcassa_client.erl, line 41)
Erlang version:
Erlang R16B02 (erts-5.10.3) [source] [64-bit] [smp:4:4] [async-threads:10] [hipe] [kernel-poll:false]

Cassandra version:
 INFO 12:59:51,051 Cassandra version: 1.1.12
 INFO 12:59:51,051 Thrift API version: 19.33.0
 INFO 12:59:51,053 CQL supported versions: 2.0.0,3.0.0-beta1 (default: 2.0.0)
```

Comment: In your `cassandra.yaml`, what is your `listen_address` set to?

Comment: port number set with 9042... But I am executing about syntax independently through application-console.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add this "https://github.com/interline/erlang-thrift" dep into your project. 
Because the code of erlcassa tries to use a function "thrift_client_util " of this dep and it can't find it because the dep has not compiled with the project.

Comment: After adding above link, I am getting this error
ERROR: Dependency dir /home/track/deps/jsx failed application validation with reason:
{version_mismatch,{"/home/track/deps/jsx/src/jsx.app.src",
                   {expected,"0.9.0"},
                   {has,"2.0.1"}}}.
ERROR: 'get-deps' failed while processing /home/track/deps/thrift: rebar_abort

Comment: Use rebar and specify your dependencies, and fetch your dependencies with `rebar get-deps`.

Comment: `%% https://github.com/ostinelli/erlcassa
%% https://github.com/interline/erlang-thrift

%% -*- mode: erlang -*-
{lib_dirs, ["deps"]}.
{erl_opts, [
    {i, "deps"},
    {src_dirs, ["src"]},
    debug_info
]}.
{eunit_opts, [verbose]}.
{deps, [
    {thrift, ".*",
     {git, "https://github.com/interline/erlang-thrift.git", {branch, "master"}}},
    {erlcassa, ".*",
     {git, "https://github.com/ostinelli/erlcassa.git", {branch, "master"}}}
]}.

{edoc_opts, [
    {application, ["YOUR_APPLICATION"]},
    {subpackages, false}
]}.
`

Comment: Yeah I have had this issue before too. I have had two dependencies that depend on different versions of jsx (erlcassa was one of them). I ended up forking erlcassa and updating to the newest version of jsx without any issues.